# How to change default Laravel 8 Fortify sent email when email request is sent?

Tags: laravel, fortify

In a Laravel 8 web application which I implemented Fortify features I would like to change the template of the email view sent when a email verification request is sent

[image]

Comment: first run this command in console inside your laravel app: php artisan vendor:publish --tag="laravel-mail" after that you will have your mails inside resources/views/vendor/mails and here you can configure your emails template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To export the components, use the `vendor:publish` Artisan command to publish the `laravel-mail` asset tag :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

This command will **publish** the Markdown mail components to the `resources/views/vendor/mail` directory. The mail directory will contain an **html** and a **text** directory, each containing their respective representations of every available component. You are free to customize these components however you like.

See the official documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#customizing-the-components)